# What´s the error in this syntax?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to do something with my Bootstrap .post-title class.

I want to put an element.style background on my post titles, which calls as a background, to the post featured image, for each post. I've already achieve this, but something went wrong and now isnt working. the only thing i know is must look something like this.

```
<div class="post-featured" style="background-image:url('upload/<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?>')">
```

but something in the syntax there is wrong, because it render this characters on HTML. whats going on?

`')">`

live example: [WP Featured post image, as a div background](http://www.picoboero.com/diseno-responsive-google-analytics-test/)

Answer (score 3):

`the_post_thumbnail` returns an IMG html tag. So the generated code is

```
<div class="post-featured" style="background-image:url('upload/<img src="path/to/file.png">')">
```

Definitely not something that could work...  You want the url only, so you should do this:

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'wpbs-featured', true);

<div class="post-featured" style="background-image:url('<?= $thumb_url[0] ?>')">
```

Comment: sorry, but what i need is to review the **<div class="post-featured" style="background-image:url('upload/<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?>')">** sentence. 3 hours later was working that way but something went wrong and stop working. im sure that **$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();**
**$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'wpbs-featured', true);** is not necesary.

Comment: i also test your suggestion and renders the same thing

Comment: @VíctorBoero you want to load the post featured image as background image, then you need the url. Look at the Wordpress codex if you doubt my words, for the `the_post_thumbnail` function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score -2):

this is the actual html snippet working.

```
<?php
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full");
$img = $img[0];
?>
<div class="postfeatured" style="<?php if($img){echo 'background:url('.$img.');';} ?>">
<div class="page-header"><h1 class="single-title" itemprop="headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>


  <h4> 
  <?php $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('_aioseop_description');
  foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
  echo substr("$value",0 ,300); //This will display the first 150 symbols
  }?>
  </h4>


  <hr>
  <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
  <div class="addthis_native_toolbox"></div>
  <hr>

  </div>

</div>
```

live example: [Design Thinking. Blog de Diseño Gráfico. Picoboero](http://www.picoboero.com/design-thinking-de-que-se-trata/)

Comment: My answer is exactly what you needed, no need to post another answer. good luck getting help from me on your next question.